# ServiceStack DateTime Deserialize Issue

Tags: datetime, servicestack

It looks like ServiceStack doesn't like me using a DateTime property as an argument in my request. I'm getting a "Bad Request" message... no other helpful detail in the exception. The inner exception shows html code (truncated), and just says "Type definitions should start with a "{" expecting serialized type 'ErrorResponse'..."

In my client:

```
    private DateTime _selectedReportDate;
    public DateTime SelectedReportDate
    {
        get { return _selectedReportDate; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _selectedReportDate, value); }
    }
    ....
    var txResults = await ServiceClient.Instance.GetAsync(new PaymentSummaries()
    {
        Date = SelectedReportDate
    });
```

Service Model:

```
[Route("/report/paymentsummaries/{Date}", "GET")]
public class PaymentSummaries : IReturn<List<PaymentSummary>>
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Service Interface:

```
[Authenticate]
public class PaymentSummariesService : Service
{
    public List<PaymentSummary> Get(PaymentSummaries request)
    {
        var results = Db.SqlList<Data.OrmLite.SpResponse.ReconcilePaymentSummaryRecord>("EXEC [Report].[ReconcilePaymentsSummary] @date", new { date = request.Date });

        return results.ConvertAll(x => x.ConvertTo<PaymentSummary>());
    }
}
```

I'm getting a "Bad Request" error.

When I change:

```
Date = SelectedReportDate
```

to

```
Date = new DateTime()
```

in the client code, it does work, and hits the Service Interface code for some reason.

**Update**

Here's the request header:

> GET
>   http://devservicestack:44345/report/paymentsummaries/2016-11-30T13%3A09%3A15.6795974-05%3A00
>   HTTP/1.1 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate Accept: application/json
>   User-Agent: ServiceStack .NET Client 4.54 Host: devservicestack:44345
>   Cookie: ss-id=F4Bt4aMonhyFQcfqmSmR; ss-pid=K6aJMA17Xw31qIVy1z8V;
>   ss-opt=temp

The response header tells me:

> [HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path
>   value was detected from the client (:).]
>   System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +9827624
>   System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +53

Comment: Could you please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Value that your are passing to is!

Comment: If you catch the exception that is thrown, what is the ErrorMessage property?

Comment: @DustinHodges nothing useful in the exception... just "Bad Request" and an inner exception saying it doesn't like that the response didn't start with a "{" (its getting back an html code as opposed to json)... working on seeing the full html message once I get Fiddler working

Comment: Please update this post to include the Raw HTTP Request/Response Headers. If it's returning HTML instead of JSON response it could be an ASP.NET Error Page containing Info about the Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When hosting ServiceStack in ASP.Net (as opposed to self-hosting), ASP.Net utilizes XSS security checks. to get around this, I can allow specific characters:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,>,*,%,&amp;,\,?" />
  </system.web>
```

(omitted ":" in requestPathInvalidCharacters)

or:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
  </system.web>
```

to disable request validation for the entire application.